# Can I use a 12V DC supply on this digital timer switch?

Tags: digital-logic, timer

I recently purchased a digital timer switch which I assumed would work at 12V DC for powering a simple circuit which takes a 12V DC supply, and has maximum power consumption of 8 watts. So the maximum current is not exceeding 800 mA at 12V.

However, to my surprise, the timer had ratings as follows:

[image]

Now, I am unsure if this would work for the circuit I have. Can someone tell me if it would, and if it would, then how it would, and if not, then why.

Comment: Ratings have spooked me to believe its switch can work on AC. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the model. Yours (or the one shown in your figure) is TM-619H-2, it works on AC200-250Vac. However, the model TM-619H-4 works on 12Vdc:

[image]

Comment: Just realized that @paul. Thanks for validating.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me. It's designed to switch either an AC or DC load. In the case of DC up to 30V and 20A well able to handle your requirement.

Comment: Validated that the relay switch inside is not activated for 12V. Tried with 220 mains, and it worked.

Comment: OK. What I meant was it is a mains powered timer switch which you can use to switch your DC load.